# Laplace Transform Simultaneous Equations

Tags: laplace-transform

If I have the matrix down below how can I get rid of I1 so I can have everything in terms of I2?

$ 
 \begin{pmatrix}
      (10+s) & (-s-6) \\
     (-s-6) &  (s+\dfrac{4}{s}+6) \\
    \end{pmatrix}  
$ 
$ \begin{pmatrix}
     I1\\
     I2\\
\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}
     \dfrac{6}{s+3}\\
     \dfrac{-6}{s}-1\\
\end{pmatrix} $

This is Laplace Transform so I can have everything in terms of $s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing by row, observing that writing $a=s+6$, $b=\frac{6}{s+3}$ and $c=-\frac{6}{s}-1$ the augmented matrix becomes
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
4+a & -a & b\\
-a & \frac{4}{s}+a & c
\end{array}
\right)\xrightarrow[]{R_2\leftrightarrow R_2+R_1}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
4+a & -a & b\\
4 & \frac{4}{s} & b+c
\end{array}
\right)\\
\xrightarrow[]{R_1\leftrightarrow \frac{R_1}{4+a}}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & -\frac{a}{4+a} & \frac{b}{4+a}\\
4 & \frac{4}{s} & b+c
\end{array}
\right)\xrightarrow[]{R_2\leftrightarrow R_2-4R_1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & -\frac{a}{4+a} & \frac{b}{4+a}\\
0 & \frac{4}{s} + \frac{4a}{4+a} & b+c-\frac{4b}{4+a}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So you have

\begin{align*}
I_2&=\frac{b+c-\frac{4b}{4+a}}{\frac{4}{s} + \frac{4a}{4+a} }\\
I_1&=\frac{b}{4+a}+\frac{a}{4+a}I_2
\end{align*}